# Unity / GooglePlay Unique identifier for online game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have developed an online game in unity for Android that allows you to sign-in with your google play account.

I've done the standard username / password approach in the past, but for player convenience I would like to use googleplay for signing-in.

When a player accesses the game, I retrieve their googleplay playerID and send that to my game server which then returns game data associated with the playerID,

I was thinking I would still need a password to secure the account, as it would be easy to spoof the PlayerID's alone..

Do I have any other options? are there any unique identifiers associated with a google play account that I could use alongside the playerID which could allow seamless access without the need of a password?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you wouldn't be sending the playerID over the network. Instead, you'd get a server auth code from the client that you send to a server you control - and use the [REST API](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api) to securely get the playerID for backend purposes.

The easiest thing to do would be to setup [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) with [Google Play Games](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/play-games) (using the newly released [PGSv2 Unity plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)). This will handle the minutiae for you, and Firebase authentication itself is a free service (although things like [cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions) aren't).

If you wish to do everything on your own backend, the [general steps](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/offline-access) you need to take are:

1. Associate a server-side application with your game
2. Get a "server auth code" to identify this client with your backend. This way the player id is never in flight.
3. Using this auth code and and your registered server-side application, retrieve an access token on the server.
4. Now you can securely retrieve things like the playerid without simply trusting the client via the REST api.